# Libgdx: отрисовка на сцене sprite элементов из массива sprites для Rectangle

Tags: java, android

необходимо при создании объекта в рандомном порядке так же отрисовывать для этого объекта спрайт.
 **final static int MAX_SPRITES = 15;**//константа. 
**spriteIndex++;** //перехожу к след. спрайту.
Массив объектов ( капель):

```
 **Array<Rectangle>  raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();**
```

Для облегчения создания дождевых капель есть  метод, называемый spawnRaindrop (), который создает новый прямоугольник, устанавливает его в случайное положение на верхнем краю экрана и добавляет его в массив каплями дождя.

```
private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 100);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 120;
    raindrop.height = 120;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);

    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

на сцене я отрисовываю так:

```
for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {

        game.batch.draw(arraySprites[spriteIndex], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        spriteIndex++;
        if (spriteIndex > MAX_SPRITES - 1) spriteIndex = 0;
    }

 arraySprites = new Sprite[15];
```

массив спрайтов из 15-ти разных спрайтов, инициализирую в таком виде

```
 r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
    r1.flip(false, true);
```

и так 15 штук.

**Проблема:**
создался первый элемент массива и ему отрисовался спрайт из массива спрайтов в рандомном порядке. На деле получается,что все спрайты тупо отрисовываются по кругу для одной капли . Т.Е НУЖНО ДЛЯ КАЖДОГО НОВОГО ПРЯМОУГОЛЬНИКА raindrop ОТРИСОВЫВАТЬ СЛУЧАЙНЫЙ СПРАЙТ ИЗ МАССИВА СПРАЙТОВ
[image: скрин]

Comment: А остальные не отрисовались? Пожалуйста, уточните, что не работает?

Comment: Кстати, для спрайтов можно использовать массив (или лист) и генерировать их можно в цикле.

Comment: @ DimXenon
добавил в тему скриншот.

Comment: Я просто опишу то, что вижу. Вы создаёте 15 спрайтов с одним и тем же рагионом (atlas.findRegion("r1") - это будет одна и та же картинка, если не менять имя региона - "r1").
Далее, по поводу расположения спрайта(ов) - на сцене присутствует несколько спрайтов в разных позициях (судя по картинке - да). Если нет - сделайте вывод в консоль координаты raindrop.x. Если да - то видимо Вам не нравится именно то, что используется одна и та же картинка. Чтобы сменить картинку - смените имя региона - используемой области загружаемого изображения. Задайте "r2", например, вместо "r1".

Comment: Только убедитесь, что для нового региона "r2" заданы все параметры: границы и т.д.

Comment: @DimXenon
r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
    r1.flip(false, true);
не с одним и тем же, я привел это как образец, у меня таких регионов 15 шт. т.е r1-r15 и все разные картинки и все выводятся в цикле и отрисовывается ,НО ТОЛЬКО очень быстро, я хочу для каждого <Rectangle>  raindrops элемента выводить только 1 спрайт из массива и так далее, создалась капля 1 отрисовалдся ей спрайт R1, создалась капля 2 отрисовался спрайт R2

Comment: А с таймерами как работаете? (Если ещё не работаете - вот примеры: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/timer.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766324/android-sprite-animations, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/games/canvas/sprite-animation-in-android/). Если обновление положения спрайта задать по таймеру (скажем, делать смену позиции для разных капель раз в 100-300 миллисекунд) - выглядеть анимация будет весьма гармонично и естественно. Вот популярная статья на тему спрайтов и их анимации https://habrahabr.ru/post/136802/.

Comment: @DimXenon
пробовал, типо в таймеер увеличивать переменную ?

Comment: Да, в задаче, передаваемой таймеру менять параметры. Какие возникли трудности?

Comment: @DimXenon
я делал так:
http://pastebin.com/1ZkcrRKr
ошибка:
https://yadi.sk/i/u1hV440ktLGZY

Comment: Правильно: если у массива length (длина) равна 15 элементов, то индекс максимальный должен быть 14 (от 0 до 14). В сообщении об ошибке говорится, что это значение было превышено.
Нужно поставить проверку значения индекса массива перед тем, как производить его модификацию и использование в извлечении значения элемента массива.

Comment: @DimXenon
сделал так,не вылетает...но что-то спрайты быстро меняются ..как и было..
http://pastebin.com/TvNB6VU5

Comment: Совет: лучше условие сделать >= 14 а не ==14. Бывает так, что значение становится больше 14 и условие не сработает.

По поводу быстрой смены спрайтов: Вы, похоже, задаёте интервал 2 миллисекунды. Попробуйте задать 500 или 1000 вместо 2 в Timer.schedule.

Comment: @DimXenon
вообщем, сделал так
http://pastebin.com/QtEbGF88
пробовал и 500 и 1000 задавать, спрайт не менялся, если делать в if
spriteIndex -- а не =0 то ,что меняется,но криво..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42547/discussion-between-upward-and-dimxenon).